# How to combine async/await with Promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, async-await

In the below code have I `createPost()` inside an `async` function, but I don't want to use `await` on it, so it blocks execution of the rest of the function. That is why I used `then`.

The outer `async` function have lots of other functions that use `await`, so that can't be changed.

**Question**

Since `createPost()` is a `async`/`await` function (see below). How can it resolve/reject to `then`/`catch` in the outer function?

```
module.exports = async (p) => {
  // lots of code here
  
 const t = await function1();      

    // lots of code here
    createPost(p).then(message => {
      // lots of code here
      console.log("ok " + message);
    }).catch(message => {
      console.log("failed " + message);
    });
};
```

**createPost()**

```
module.exports = async (p) => {
  // lots of code here
  try {
    const r = await getStat();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  };
};
```

Comment: Why is that first module `async`?

Comment: unfortunately i didn't understand your question, Can you describe more... What you  trying to do?

Comment: Your try-catch block in your `createPost()` will catch your exceptions, so you can remove the try-catch at the `createPost()` level so that any errors will cause a rejected promise to be returned and then handled within the `.catch()`

Comment: @Andy I have now updated OP where I have specified that there are other `await` functions, so that is why the outer function is `async`.

Comment: @Nur The problem I have is since the outer function have to be `async`. See updated OP. And I don't want to use `await` on `createPost()` as that would block execuation of the remaining code in the outer function. What changes do I need to make to `createPost()` so I can use then/catch in the outer function? Or with other words: How do I specify `message` that the outer function gets?

Comment: @NickParsons Now updated OP. So I guess another way to ask would be: How do I specify `message` that the outer function gets?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting "*What changes do I need to make to `createPost()` so I can use `then/catch` in the outer function?*" - uh, none? An `async function` always returns a promise, and you can simply invoke `.then()` on that. "*How do I specify `message` that the outer function gets?*" - well, your `createPost` implementation doesn't `return` anything, so the promise always resolves to `undefined`.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. If I could mark your comment as the answer I would do that =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async` / `await` is a more modern equivilant to `.then` / `.catch`.
In this case you have mixed the syntaxes of both.
You don't need `try` / `catch` blocks when using `.then`,
just like you don't need to declare a function as `async` when using the `try` / `catch` syntax.

Other than that there's no reason they can't work together in seperate functions.

```js
module.exports = (p) => {
  createPost(p).then(message => {
    console.log("ok " + message);
  }).catch(message => {
    console.log("failed " + message);
  });
};
```

`createPost():`

```js
module.exports = async (p) => {
  try {
    const r = await getStat();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  };
};
```

Comment: There are other functions that use `await` in the outer function, so it have to `async`. How does that change your answer?

Comment: Well in that case you do need to leave the `async` in place in order for the `await` to work, there shouldn't be a problem with that. Though I would advise sticking with one method in general unless there is any clear justification in using both. I think that would make it less confusing in the long run.

Comment: Ok, very nice. Can I specify the content of `message` as one can do in Promise `resolve()` / `reject()` functions?

Answer (score 1):

An `async` decleration on a function is redundant and wrong if you're not using the `await` keyword inside.

await/async are often referred to as syntactic sugar, and let us wait for something (e.g. an API call), giving us the illusion that it is synchronous in an actual asynchronous code, which is a great benefit.

The things you want to acheive with async/await is is possible with promises but the advantages of async/await. let's an example with this code:

```js
const makeRequest = () => //promise way
  getJSON()
    .then(data => {
      return data
    })

makeRequest();

const makeRequest = async () => { //async await way
  const data = await getJSON();
  return data;
 }

makeRequest()
```

Why is async/await prefered over promise?

1. **Concise and clean** -  We didn’t have to write .then and create an anonymous function to handle the response, or give a name data to a variable that we don’t need to use. We also avoided nesting our code. async/await is a lot cleaner.
2. **Error handling** - Async/await makes it finally possible to handle both synchronous and asynchronous errors with the same try/catch format.
3. **Debugging** - A really good advantage when using async/await is that it’s much easier to debug then promises for 2 reasons: 1) you can’t set breakpoints in arrow functions that return expressions (no body). 2) if you set a breakpoint inside a .then block and use debug shortcuts like step-over, the debugger will not move to the the following .then because it only “steps” through synchronous code.
4. **Error stacks** - The error stack returned from promises chain gives us no idea of where the error occured and can be misleading. async/await gives us the error stack from async/await points to the function that contains the error which is a really big advantage.

Comment: I have now updated OP, where I explain why I have `async` in the outer function. So perhaps another way to ask the same question would be: How can I specify `message` that the outer function gets?